# What does "mossette" translate to in English

Tags: word-meaning

What does "*mossette*" mean? It's not listed in the dictionaries I looked up. I'm guessing there's no appropriate English translation?

Example sentences:

- tra **mossette** e gridolini fissa gli spettatori con stupore.
- I primi gridolini, certe **mossette** piene di grazia di Ninnì lo facevano impazzire dalla gioja.
- È cosa ben diversa, dunque, dal vedere Elliott Gould, stessa classe anagrafica, dibattersi tra **mossette** d'altri tempi in Mulaney.

Comment: It's just a diminutive form of _mossa_; see this [dictionary article](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mossa) @ Treccani, especially the end.

Comment: @DaG This ought to be an answer

Comment: Fatto, @DenisNardin. Ora però scrivi quella su qualcuno/alcuno... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suffix *-etto* (*-etta* for the feminine) is often used in Italian, appending it to a noun, to denote a smaller, and often nicer and cuter, version of the object or creature denoted by that noun. It's called a *diminutivo* or a *vezzeggiativo* of the original noun.

So, a *casetta* is a small, possibly nice, house (*casa*); a *pescetto* is a small *pesce*, if Chiara is a child, or a close friend of yours, you might possibly call her Chiaretta, and so on. Note that this process is not automatic: not all nouns admit this suffix (for instance, a small cat, *gatto*, is never called a **gattetto*, possibly for euphonic reasons).

Dictionaries tend not to register regular derivations of this kind (or other ones that are used similarly: *-ino*, *-one* and so on) or to just list them quickly at the end of the main lemma if they are often used in that form (as is the case for *mossetta* under [*mossa*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mossa)), unless the new word has actually an autonomous meaning. For instance, *libretto*, while literally meaning “small book” (and being occasionally used in this sense), has as its main meaning that of a “libretto” (English), the text of an opera.

So, in our case, a *mossetta* is simply a small, cute, perhaps simpering move. How to exactly translate it into English is beyond the scope of Italian.SE.

For more (in Italian) about this phenomenon in the Italian language, see the articles [“alterazione”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/alterazione_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/), [“vezzeggiativi”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/vezzeggiativi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) and [“diminutivo”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/diminutivo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) in Treccani's *Enciclopedia dell'italiano*.

Comment: Thank you for the kind elaboration. Grazie mille!